# How to change directory folder for images in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have form in php which upload photo from computer folder to mysql database. Photos I have in a folder "img" but files added to database are without any folder.  How I can change directory?

My code echo is:

```
echo "<center><img src=" . $row["Photos"] . "></center>";
```

I've tried something like this:

```
echo "<center><img src="/img/ . $row["Photos"] . "></center>";
```

but it doesn't work.

I don't have any idea where I can find solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo "<center><img src='/img/" . $row["Photos"] . "'></center>";`|

Because your folder img must be in html tag

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
echo '<center><img src="/img/' . $row["Photos"] . '"></center>';
```

You have set your quotes on the wrong char.
In this case you must work with single quotes and normal quotes. Or you must encode your douple quotes like this:

```
echo "<center><img src=\"/img/" . $row["Photos"] . "></center>";
```